# Remove duplicates from list but only keep some

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Given an array

```
[1,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,5,6,7]
```

as input. How do i filter the list so that it outputs

```
[1,2,3,2,4,5,6,7]
```

?

Note that

```
[2,2] -> [2]
```

,also

```
[1,2,2,1] -> [1,2,1]
[1,2,3,3,2,1] -> [1,2,3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
In [1]: lst = [1,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,5,6,7]

In [2]: from itertools import groupby

In [3]: [next(g) for _,g in groupby(lst)]
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is two pointer problem. Here is the pseudo code:

```
start = 0
end = 1
while(end < len(arr)):
    if(arr[end] != arr[start]):
        arr[start + 1] = arr[end]
        start += 1
    end += 1
# end of while loop

# now arr[0... start] holds the result
```

Time complexity `O(n)` with constant space.

Answer (score 0):

Another method using zip:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7]
>>> [i for i,j in zip(a, a[1:] + [not a[-1]]) if i != j]
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```